# Kivy Image Colours Distorted

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to using Kivy. When I source an image, regardless of format or where it is sourced to, it always has distorted colours. What may be causing this? Below I have left an example of the code I use and an Imgur link with the outcome. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class ColoursApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Image(source = "colours.png")


ColoursApp().run()
```

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ySl.jpg)

Comment: Does that mean all the default kivy widgets using images also have distorted colours?

Comment: Sourcing images in other Kivy widgets results in the same issue. I can change the colours of Kivy widgets and they reflect the RGBa input given, but any images fail to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, my problem stemmed from graphical issues related to using a Chrome OS Linux container. I had been running my Kivy application from this container, but all image formats were flipped from RGB to BGR. I suspect the issue arises due to how OpenGL functions within the Debian container, as I have previously found that Vulkan drivers cannot be installed inside the container. Since posting this question, I have compiled the application with Buildozer. I can now confirm the the application runs correctly on Android, both on a real device and when emulated on Chrome OS. So even though my application appears distorted when run from the Linux container, it exports fine to Android, and presumably all other platforms.